# Need to pull the item content from RSS feeds into new file in PERL

Tags: perl, rss

I am beginner to PERL..  I would like to get the ITEM's which are listed under CHannel into different output file.

```
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>XYZ</title>
            <item>
                <title>ITEM1</title>    
            </item>
            <item>
                <title>ITEM1</title>        
            </item>
             </channel>
    <rss>
```

In output file I want only ITEM content listed within  tag.

Like below :

```
    <ITEMS>
            <item>
                <title>ITEM1</title>    
            </item>
                <item>
                <title>ITEM1</title>    
            </item>
    </ITEMS>
```

Please help or suggest ?

I tried match operator as well. to match with ITEM and then pull. but nothing works.. please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although you say you are a beginner, it will still help answer the question if you add some code showing what you have tried. Otherwise, someone answering has to put a whole solution together. You probably already know how to open a file and put the content into a scalar, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Use `XML::Feed` ([docs are here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Feed/lib/XML/Feed.pm)) to parse your rss and then get the item-elements and do whatever you want to do with it.